# Fixed address bar url zend framework app

Tags: apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, registrar

So first of, hi,
I have probably a simple issue but I'm not expert enough to figure out what the problem is. 
I just deployed a zend framework application on a debian server. I have dotster as registrar and another provider for the dedicated server. The problem is about the domain mapping and the urls when navigating from page to page within the app.
Basically when I use the server ip, like 91.121.121.171/public/ to reach the app, the url works just fine and displays well in the address bar like 91.121.121.171/public/directory/dir-comp for example. But when I use the url [www.ceramstar.org](http://ceramstar.org) this stays fixed. Did I mess up with dotster config or Apache rewrite rule?
I must say I don't really get how to configure things properly on the dotster side...
Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: How did you actually map the domain to the IP? It sounds like you just redirected it or masked in and iframe or something.

Comment: Yes i think that's what is happening as I'm just using the pointers section (Set up the domain home directory or forward location.) in the dotster manager. The thing is that I didn't clearly find how to map a domain to an ip in their interface... Thanks

Comment: You should change DNS settings in your domain control panel to point your domain to correct server.